# sqlite3 prints without explicit command

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to get a rowid if a data row exists. What I have now is

```
row_id = self.dbc.cursor.execute("SELECT ROWID FROM Names where unq_id=?",(namesrow['unq_id'],)).fetchall()[0][0]
```

where namesrow is a dictionary of column names with corresponding data to fill into the table. The problem is this prints 'unq_id' when runs and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

I'm using sqlite3 and python. Any help's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

quoting the sqlite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key
>   that consists of a single column and the declared type of that column
>   is "INTEGER" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column
>   becomes an alias for the rowid.

So if your unq_id is the integer primary key in this table, then rowid and unq_id will be the same field.